# How to insert the name of the image out of the database image_tag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to insert the name of the image out of the database image_tag?

```
<% @vis.each do |vis| %>

    <%= image_tag( "(value  vis.picture here).jpg", :width =>247, :crop => :fit) %> </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Depends on how you are storing them in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the attribute of your model that has the url of your image, guessing from your code is `vis.picture`:

```
<% @vis.each do |vis| %>
    <%= image_tag(vis.picture, :width =>247, :crop => :fit) %> </div>
<% end %>
```